# Selenium webdriver .getText vs .getAttribute

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, java

Having a slight issue that I solved on my own but I would like an explanation as to why .getText does not work.

So I had it create a random email

```
private static  String randomEmail() {
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".20." + "xxxxx@spamgourmet.com";
```

I then wanted it to copy the email I just made with this code.

```
final String emailRandom = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='step5']/input")).getText
```

This however did not actually copy anything, everytime I tried to make it use the code via:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='reset-password-wrap']/form/div[1]/input")).sendKeys(emailRandom);
```

Nothing would come up or be pasted.

I switched the `.getText` to `.getAttribute("value");` and it works flawlessly.

**Question:** Why does `.getText` not work but `.getAttribute` work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With all the regular elements, you would use `getText()` to get the "text" of an element, but `input` elements ([W3C `input` form control spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element)) are special - the "text" is kept under the `value` attribute.

Related threads:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852287/using-selenium-web-driver-to-retrieve-value-of-a-html-input
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922921/why-gettext-method-returns-empty-string

Comment: Thanks, did not realize the input would not be covered by getText, your answer makes sense. cheers.